# MySQL - Select distinct 2 columns and return all

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

First of all, I'm relatively new to MySQL and I'm confused after searching about `SELECT DISTINCT`

My situation is the following:

I have a MySQL table with several columns and hundreds of rows. Each row represents a different product (shirts). It looks like this (simplified):

```
unique_id | model | color | slots | (...)
-----------------------------------
0943535   |  100  |  10   | ab
0943546   |  100  |  10   | ab
0943551   |  100  |  23   | ab
0943562   |  103  |  10   | fk
0943567   |  103  |  10   | fk
0943578   |  103  |  17   | fk
0943582   |  169  |  09   | dv
(...)
```

Unique_id represents a unique item number. That value is different for each single row in the database.

2 shirts are equal if both `model` and `color` are the same.

Like so, I want to print a list (PHP script) with all the columns of the avaliable items in the database but so that the (visually) identical items (the ones of same `model` and `color`) are only displayed once. The output should be something like this:

```
unique_id | model | color | slots | (...)
-----------------------------------
0943535   |  100  |  10   | ab
0943551   |  100  |  23   | ab
0943567   |  103  |  10   | fk
0943578   |  103  |  17   | fk
0943582   |  169  |  09   | dv
(...)
```

I was told that this should be done using `Select distinct` in the sql query.

Again, I want to select all columns, excluding duplicates of same `model` and`color`.

Please show me what my MySQL query should look like.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter if you lose the unique id or do you have a preference to which unique id to return? You could do a GROUP BY model, color and that would return what you need.

Comment: SO really needs to post up a list of the most frequently asked questions relating to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use group by instead:

```
SELECT unique_id, model, color, slots FROM table_name GROUP BY model, color
```

Comment: Indeed. It was as simple as that! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the GROUP BY Clause to solve you problem.. so the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY model, color
```